# Brief tty screen before boot login screen shows up

Tags: nvidia, login, tty

After I installed an NVIDIA graphics driver, a tty login screen appears about halt a second just before the lightdm shows up. When the system used nouveau open source driver, the computer didn't show anything like this. Is there something wrong with my installation? So far, nothing strange came out except for this tty login screen....  If this is OK, is there any way to get rid of that brief tty screen during boot?

Thank you and I use Ubuntu 14.04.1 and nvidia-331 from the standard Ubuntu source.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your installation, this is normal.
As far as I know, there is no way to get rid of the brief message. But it's harmless.